# Is it possible to set placeholder path params with OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I have an url `http://example.com/{x}/push/{y}` and I'm using OkHttp curl it.

```
final HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl
                .parse("http://example.com/{x}/push/{y}")
                .newBuilder()
                ???
                .build();
```

Is it possible to set these `{x}` and `{y}` path params?
I can see method like `addPathSegment` which is somehow related, but not what I want.

Comment: Can you do simple string concatenation? E.g. `.parse("http://example.com/"+ x +"/push/" y )` And x and y are passed to the function or something. I've done it this way in my app.

Comment: Actually I can but it looks ugly for me especially when I'm using HttpUrl class to add some query params to end.

Comment: Well, edge case - do it the ugly way. I've seen that injection that you speak of in other programming languages, don't know if it's possible in Java.

Comment: Yes sure, but I'm using this highlevel builder and it would be great if there would be such functionality to set this path placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one technique that might help you to get started.

```
HttpUrl template = HttpUrl.parse("http://example.com/{a}/b/{c}");
HttpUrl.Builder builder = template.newBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < template.pathSegments().size(); i++) {
  String parameter = template.pathSegments().get(i);
  String replacement = null;

  if (parameter.equals("{a}")) {
    replacement = "foo";
  } else if (parameter.equals("{c}")) {
    replacement = "bar";
  }

  if (replacement != null) {
    builder.setPathSegment(i, replacement);
  }
}

HttpUrl url = builder.build();
```

Comment: C'mon isn't it ugly for you? I would say String.format looks nicer.

Comment: That depends on what your goals are. If the replacement strings can have special characters in them like `?` or `#`, then `String.format()` might give you the wrong URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `HttpUrl.setPathSegment(index, value)` can make it look a bit better :D

Answer (score 0):

```
fun HttpUrl.insertPathSegment(index: Int, pathSegment: String): HttpUrl {

val newPathSegments: ArrayList<String> =
    encodedPathSegments().fold(ArrayList()) { acc, oldPathSegment ->

        printLog("OkHttp", "insertPathSegment oldPathSegment:$oldPathSegment ")

        acc.add(oldPathSegment)
        acc
    }

return newBuilder().apply {
    try {

        newPathSegments.add(index, pathSegment)
        addEncodedPathSegment("")

        newPathSegments.forEachIndexed { index, path ->

            printLog("OkHttp", "insertPathSegment setEncodedPathSegment:$index $path ")
            setEncodedPathSegment(index, path)

            //printLog("OkHttp", "insertPathSegment setPathSegment:$index $path ")
            //setPathSegment(index, path)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}.build()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach to pass path variables:

```
inputUrl= http://localhost:8080/getResults/firstName/%s/lastName/%s

HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.get(String.format(inputUrl, "fn","ln"));

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
```